# How do I call the values that I have defined in another function to the other function?

Tags: python

The problem that I have is that it says missing 3 required arguments when I try to pass it to the the other function, the arguments that I want to pass are guess_word, jug_words, and random_words so that I can use it for comparison

```
def InputData():
   guess_word = input("Guess a word")
   jug_words = GetJugWords()
   random_words = GetRandomLetters()

def Score(jug_words, random_words, guess_word):
    score = 0

    while True:
        print("Your phrase is: ", random_words)
        guess_word = input("Guess a word: ")
        score +=score
        if len(guess_word) == 2 or len(guess_word) ==3 :
            score += 1
        elif len(guess_word) == 4:
            score += 2
        elif len(guess_word) == 5:
            score += 3
        elif len(guess_word) == 6 or len(guess_word) == 7:
            score += 5
        elif len(guess_word) == 8:
            score += 8

        if guess_word not in jug_words and random_words:
            print("Game Over!")
            break
        print("Your score is now", str(score))
    print(f"your total score: {score}")
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you return the values from your `InputData()` function.
The current variables you are using do not exist outside the scope of the function.

You can return as a tuple, e.g.

```
def InputData():
    ...    
    return  guess_word, jug_words, random_words
```

Then you can unpack the variables directly when you call the function:

```
guess_word, jug_words, random_words = InputData()
Score(jug_words, random_words, guess_word)
```